# mongoose createConnection not start and no errors

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I maked multiple db app. All worked correctly when I connected my code to db. But now... My app connecting to the port, but db connection not fired. Thats mean that all my connections stay on `readyState = 2`. No errors, no connections. I checked other files about 500 times - there is no other connections. My connection code:

```
const connectionOptions = {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  auto_reconnect: true,
  socketTimeoutMS: 0,
  keepAlive: true,
  reconnectTries: 30,
}

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.main_conn = mongoose.createConnection(config.db.url, connectionOptions);
mongoose.hist_conn = mongoose.createConnection(config.db.hist, connectionOptions);

mongoose.main_conn.on("connected", function(){
  console.log("Mongoose connected to " + config.db.url);
});

mongoose.main_conn.on("error", function(err){
  console.log("Mongoose connection error" + err);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The error was stupid. But maybe my answer will be some helpful for others. In one file of the application I used javascript's `sleep`, when `setTimeout` called in `Promise`. And I maked an error inside it:

```
function sleep (ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve(), ms));
}
```

As you see, I maked endless loop. It called before connection was done, and freezed my app. After I fixed this error the app work's correctly:

```
function sleep (ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(), ms));
}
```